# Converting dates with R using as.POSIXct

Tags: r, date, time

I’m working with dates and R and I’m converting dates using the `as.POSIXct` function. I have a pretty good understanding of how to convert dates by just looking at the `?strptime` docs. However I’m confused about why this specific conversion doesn’t work as expected (see below).

```
date_string <- "03/11/2017, 3:14:32 pm"
as.POSIXct(date_string, format = "%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S",tz="PST8PDT")

> [1] "2017-03-11 03:14:32 PST"
```

I’m losing 12 hours of time with this conversion, I’m expecting this..

```
> [1] "2017-03-11 15:14:32 PST"
```

I’ve tried using ‘%r’ with my formatting but that always gives me NA’s? Can somebody explain what R is doing here, and why it’s not converting this date string as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes:

- you used `%H` where you want `%I` for the dreaded 12-hour format
- you omitted `%p` to catch the "pm" marker

With that corrected:

```
R> date_string <- "03/11/2017, 3:14:32 pm"
R> as.POSIXct(date_string, format = "%m/%d/%Y, %I:%M:%S %p",tz="PST8PDT")
[1] "2017-03-11 15:14:32 PST"
R>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you!